# SSRS - "Print We'll create a printer-friendly PDF version of your report."

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, printing

All Reports when click the print button open a PDF option with

[image]

but I want to print straight to the print.

I've tried to change a few configurations on SSRS but does not work, my research so far:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/enable-and-disable-client-side-printing-for-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

This thread and its linked pages answers the challenge completely

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a631f79-a116-49b7-8f55-826c050a38ce/printing-from-ssrs-2016-dirrectly-to-printer-without-pdf-reader?forum=sqlreportingservices

http://printssrsreport.blogspot.com/

https://neelb.wordpress.com/2018/09/26/ssrs-enable-disable-client-side-printing/

Microsoft has intentionally limited direct printing without intervention for good reason.

In all scenarios printing reports is bad -- data is out of date immediately, paper wastage, print server administration (and automation if you go down that route)

Reading through the noise - Chrome browser offers a marginally better experience because it has an inbuilt PDF viewer - so the user experience would marginally better than having to open a separate application to view the PDF - from Chrome the facility to print the PDF is trivial

Answer (score -2):

To achieve this, you need to do some programing using c#. I am not sure that you have this option available for you or not. In case, if you would like to see how it that code looks like refer below link. This might help. Even you can setup default printer and pass parameters like username, date range etc. I was looking for a way to set default printer using code and found this link.

[ReportExecutionService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render?view=sqlserver-2016)